# dynamically creating variable names and instantiating them(Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, unityscript

Hi I am new to unity and I am trying to create an AI script for an enemy. In this class I have way-points that the enemy will walk to randomly by generating a random number originally I had four way-points but this was very linear. So I added more to make it appear as if the enemy is aimlessly walking around an example can be seen by this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMSQaS1o1Kw. I then added in around twenty more way points to complete randomize it but I don't want to instantiate every one of them so I am wondering is there anyway possible to instatiatie them in a for loop?

Here's how my code for doing it looks so far:

```
private var player : GameObject;
private var way0 : GameObject;
private var way1 : GameObject;
private var way2 : GameObject;
private var way3 : GameObject;

function Start()
{
    player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    way0 = GameObject.Find("way0");
    way1 = GameObject.Find("way1");
    way2 = GameObject.Find("way2");
    way3 = GameObject.Find("way3");
}
```

Everything else is dealt with in the update function through if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an array to store the waypoints that you need. Like this:

```
private var waypoints : Array;

function Start() {
  player = GameObject.Find("Player");
  waypoints = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < WaypointCount; ++i) {
     waypoints.Push(GameObject.Find("way" + i)); //Push the waypoint in the array.
  }
  DoSomethingWith(waypoints[0]); //This is "way0".
}
```

Where `WaypointCount` is the number of waypoints that you wish to push. More exactly, the number of waypoints that satisfy the naming pattern that you use. In the example that you posted, `WaypointCount` is 4.

Comment: This is just a follow on question when i use this method the object give a null reference when I use them later. An example is as seen 

`var distance= Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, **waypoints[variable]**.transform.position);`

variable is just a number pushed into a function. but its not setting the variable as it gets a null reference. @AlexM.

Comment: Edited the answer, sorry about that!